# copying sample.db file from app's document directory to local safari/databases directory using xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

im developing uiwebview in my app.
this UIWebView displays HTML5 pages and has javascript which access local db and displays lists of menu.

Problem is that i need to copy this database from app's document directory and paste it to safari/databases folder..so that my javascript file can access this db and display list of files.

however no success in copying file from document folder to safari/Databases folder 
here is my code:

```
    NSString *databasepath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"~/Library/%@/%@",@"safari",@"databases"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;

NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sfa.db" ofType:nil];
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:databasepath error:&error];
```

Any help will b appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks for all of ur replies. although it doesnt solve my problem..

1) I want javascript to connect with existing sqlite3 database located in my app's document directory.
2) but OpenDatabase() method always points to safari/databases directory

3) either i get a way to b able to point **document directory** in OpenDatabase() method
OR 
 some other way to keep a copy of my sqlite3 database from my app's **document directory** to Safari/Databases

OR
any other way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using function stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString
here is my code:

in my model:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
//getMenuItems is fetches items from database
    [self getMenuItems];
//array items converted to string seperated by ","
     NSString *string = [[arr valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];

//load is javascript function
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"load('%@');",string];

[web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:str]; 
}
```

in my html

```
   function load(example_array){
        var example_array=example_array.split(",");
    var select = document.getElementById("ddlMenu");

        for(i=0;i<=example_array.length-1;i++) {
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(example_array[i], i);
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have write-permissions outside of your app's sandbox. While this might work on the Simulator, it won't on device.

You will need to find a different solution. One way might be to call a javascript function in the webview from your ViewController to copy the data: `-(void) stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`

Comment: Please give a little detail about how can i use                        -(void) stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString for copying data from app's document directory to Safari/Databases

Comment: You could for instance pass the base64 encoded file-data into a javascript function. You can execute any javascript you like using that function. How exactly this works will depend on the complexity of your database and the available javascript methods.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString * returnValue = [WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"SOME JAVASCRIPT"];
```

You can try this one.